# Why do some rxjava operators have scheduler parameters and others not?

Tags: rx-java

I went through the docs for rxjava 1 and the following operators had variants with scheduler parameters:
Buffer
Debounce
Delay
Delaysubscription
From
Interval
Range
Repeat
repeatWhen
replay
retrywhen
sample
skip
skiplast

Can someone explain the rationale for these and not others?

Comment: you should ask the developers of it, not us.

Comment: Please spend your own time discovering the paradigm and library first.

Comment: Daniel, who's "us".  I thought this list would include the developers.

Comment: akarnokd, You're right, I was being lazy.  It appears that at least generally that variants with scheduler parameters are provided for time based operators and others which might block.  I guess one can always use observeOn otherwise..I wouldn't mind hearing from a developer but I guess we can put this one to bed.

Answer (score 3):

Operators that require time or have asynchronous aspects take a `Scheduler` parameter that allow you to customize where the operator performs its work. Usually, overloads exist with a default `Scheduler` applied for convenience.

`Scheduler` is an abstraction over an asynchronous boundary that offers executing tasks, `Runnable`s, with or without delay and provide a notion of current time. This abstraction enables the use of `Scheduler`s that are not really asynchronous or even execute tasks with real time delay: the `trampoline` scheduler and the `TestScheduler` respectively for example.

They form the non-blocking basis for switching threads in a flow via `observeOn` and offer non-blocking execution of delayed tasks, such as starting a new buffer after some time or emitting a value periodically. Without them, you'd have to resort to `Thread.sleep()` which then blocks the current thread and potentially wastes it.

If you have to interact with non-reactive sources or APIs, there is a likelihood those APIs are blocking by themselves: reading bytes from disk, waiting on a socket's `InputStream`, etc. `Scheduler`s let you move this blocking out of some threads such as the Android Main Thread or the Swing Event Dispatch Thread, which frees these threads to perform their main duty: rendering the user interface and reacting to user input.

Therefore, when you see a `Scheduler` parameter, it can mean:

- event/flow management should happen on a different thread (`observeOn`, `subscribeOn`),
- timing information is needed (`replay`, testing with `TestScheduler`),
- event(s) should happen over time that affect a primary flow (buffering with time, emitting events after some quiet time), or
- avoid blocking the current thread (`from` with `Future`, a non-reactive API wrapped into `Observable`).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that variants with scheduler parameters are provided where there is the possibility of blocking (though it's not clear to me why we need these given that we have observeOn.)